# String literals manipulation - copying characters

Tags: c++, string, copy, character

I am trying to implement a simple string copy in the following code.

However, I got a run-time error in the line "*d = *c;".

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with that?

```
void test3()
{
    char *a="123456";
    char *b="000000";

    char *c=a;
    char *d=b;

    while(*c){
        *d = *c;
        cout << *c << endl;
        c++;
        d++;
    }

    *d='\0';
}
```

Comment: `char *a="123456"` is deprecated in C++ and banned in C++11. Use `char const* a`. Or, ideally, sack this whole thing off and use `std::string` like everybody else.

Comment: Oh, and `endl` within a tight loop is a complete waste. You don't need the flush. Write `cout << *c << '\n';` instead.

Comment: ...and another question that could have been [avoided](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105838/feature-request-tips-hints-based-on-tags) if the OP had enabled and listened to compiler warnings.

Comment: @Kerrek: My GCC 4.4.1 warns without being asked. (Just `g++ test.cpp -o test`).

Comment: @Tomalak: Funnily, my GCC 4.6.1 *allows* it even with `-std=c++0x` (with a warning, of course). The weighting between "enable warnings" and "listen to warnings" varies from case to case, of course ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, string litterals are constant and can't be changed.  In the following line:

```
char *a="123456";
```

`char *a` should be replaced with `const char * a` because `a` points to a block of constant memory.  Further down the function, you attempt to change that block of constant memory and this yields a run-time error.

To get a real character array that you can use in such a function, you should use:

```
char a[] = "123456";
```

This will produce a mutable (non-const) array that you can manipulate freely.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot change const data. These strings you provide (literal strings) are stored in a read-only region of the program. In fact, any string literal you provide in your program, say `"000000"`, is considered `const char*` (pointer to const chars), so you are not allowed (not advised, at least) to modify them.

Comment: It's not considered `const char*` until C++11. However it _is_ undefined to write to this memory.

Comment: @Tomalak C++03 says it's const too, "An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char”" in 2.13.4[lex.string]/1.

Comment: @Cubbi: Arrays and pointers are not the same thing. And 4.2/2: `A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to char”;` And I think both Diego and I mean "considered (after conversion to pointer type)".

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to modify a literal, which the compiler will generally place in a read-only part of the executable; modern processors have hardware locks to keep this from happening as an aid against viruses.

You can fix it by providing your own character array, which can be initialized with the literal:

```
char b[] = "000000";
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `*d=*c` and `*d='\0'` are broken because you may not change these values that come from string literals. They are non-modifiable. If you'd used `const` like you're supposed to, then you would have not made this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have assigned both pointers c and d to constant strings, you can't change them!  You would need to allocate a char array for d in order for this to work:

```
char d[MAX_CHAR];
```